# Active class works with error but not message and warning

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component with a member called `capsLockIsOn`. And this works perfectly:

```
<div class="error" [class.active]="capsLockIsOn">Caps is on!</div>
```

However, when I change to `class="warning"` or `class="message"` it does not work. By "it does not work" I mean that it's constantly showing "Caps is on!" regardless if it's on or off. The code in the component is simply this:

```
this.CapsLockIsOn = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
```

But as I said. It works for class error, but not warning and message. Why? And how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like there is no css describing the "active" state on your `warning` and `message` classes.

What you want to do is add the same class properties you have on your error with active, to `warning` and `message`.

So somewhere is your stylesheets you have something like:

```
.error.active{
  ...
}
```

but not:

```
.warning.active{
  ...
}
.danger.active{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sounds very plausible. Investigating it now.

Comment: You were correct about that. However, I created those and copied the body from .error.active, but it did not work. Same result.

Comment: If you inspect the element in the browser with Command + Shift + C or Control + Shift + C, do you see your <div> actually get the right classes? I would recommend to look here. Then that would mean the element does not get the "correct" class. What exactly is the properties of the error active class. That can help me help you

Comment: Yeah, seems like that is a problem. But I need to go now because my job is closing. Thanks anyway, och fantastiskt användarnamn!

Comment: Ok, I admit that I stayed a little longer, but I managed to solve it thanks to you.

Comment: @klutt haha tack, I'm glad you were able to solve it!

Comment: We'll see if the changes get approved